# rails 4 bootstrap 3 modal dialog: weird layout rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, devise

My Bootstrap modal for signing in with Devise is rendering in a weird way:
[image: modal]

I inserted in the application_controller.rb either the bootstrap helper from twitter-bootstrap-rails:

```
<%= modal_dialog id: "signin",
         header: { show_close: true, dismiss: 'modal', title: 'Modal header' },
         body:   { content: 'This is the body' },
         footer: { content: content_tag(:button, 'Save', class: 'btn') } %>
```

or tried with plain html as well:

```
<div id="signin" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Both render in the same was as in the picture above.
The log says:

```
I, [2015-09-04T10:13:45.228876 #7182]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/sign_in.js" for xx.xx.xx.xx at 2015-09-04 10:13:45 +0200
I, [2015-09-04T10:13:45.237032 #7182]  INFO -- : Processing by SessionsController#new as JS
I, [2015-09-04T10:13:45.256132 #7182]  INFO -- :   Rendered devise/sessions/_signin.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-09-04T10:13:45.259590 #7182]  INFO -- :   Rendered devise/sessions/_signin.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-09-04T10:13:45.261021 #7182]  INFO -- :   Rendered mailgroups/_mailgroup_append.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-09-04T10:13:45.264283 #7182]  INFO -- :   Rendered devise/sessions/_signin.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-09-04T10:13:45.264459 #7182]  INFO -- :   Rendered devise/sessions/new.js (11.7ms)
I, [2015-09-04T10:13:45.264907 #7182]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 25.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My sessions_controller.rb is:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  respond_to :js

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end

  def failure
    logger.debug "failure in devise sessions_controller"
  end

end
```

/views/devise/sessions/new.js looks as follows:

```
$("#signin").modal()
```

The file /views/devise/sessions/_signin.html.erb is empty (I like to put the modal code from application_controller.rb there as soon it's rendering ok.)

My questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong (Big uncertainity in sessions_controller) ?
2. Why is devise/sessions/_signin.html.erb being
   rendered 3 times (as the log says, currently it's empty, but when I put some code there, it's being executed multiple times...)
3. If I move the modal code from
   application_controller into _signin.html.erb, what do I need to put
   into application_controller.rb? ( e.g.   )

Comment: If you have scaffolded your app, you should probably remove `scaffolds.css` from your stylesheets folder.

Comment: `scaffold.css`has been removed at beginning of the project already.

Answer (score 0):

How embarassing... 
After searching 3 hours, I found a remaining definition for my #signin id in the `application.css.less`, which messed up the layout.

Sorry guys for keeping you busy and thanks to Ruby Racer for pointing my into the right direction. It was indeed a CSS issue.